# Shortcut for Finding the Table in SQL Server Management

Tags: sql-server, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the shortcut to navigate to a table ?

For ex. The query is,

```
SELECT * FROM ABCTABLE
```

Is there any shortcut key that I can click after placing the cursor on ABCTABLE and navigate to the table ABCTABLE on Object Explorer. And do you suggest any good source detailing all shortcuts etc for beginners?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can select the word/object (table name) and use the shortcut `Alt+F1` to know that particular table/object details.

You can use the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver15) to know more SQL Server Management Studio Keyboard Shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Using SSMSBoost:

[Locate Object in Object Explorer focused in SQL Editor](https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-locate-object-in-object-explorer)

> Locate object in Object Explorer located at cursor position directly from SQL Editor.
>
> Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Whether this option work in all the SSMS without any additional settings?

Comment: @SurajKumar Unfortunately SSMS itself does not support such functionality.